# Add extra legends in highcharts using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

i am using Highcharts with react.
I have a line chart with two lines. I want to add some extra customised legends which have no interactions. Those extra legends are just for the view. Existing legends should not loose its interactivity and view.
I want to add extra customised legends without disturbing the interactivity and view of the existing legends

I want to add extra customised legends without disturbing the interactivity and view of the existing legends

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a new empty series to achieve this.

**Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/legend-item-nmzgvm

Comment: marker: {
          symbol: "circle",
        },
        type: "column"

I have added type also, so chart is loosing line chart default properties